# how to embed html iframe on Python tkinter app

Tags: html, python-3.x, tkinter, iframe

I would like to know how its possible to embed a chart iframe html content from a web app into tkinter

I haven't tried yet, but I have seen a few modules such as tkhtmlview, but it isn't a web browser, so it probably won't work well for what I am looking for

I've seen also CEFPython, but the latest release dates to Feb 2021.

Any other choices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tkinter Frame widget and the "WebView" widget from the "pywebview" library.
**pip install pywebview**

```
import tkinter as tk
import webview

def load_webpage():
    webview.load_url('path/to/your/html/file.html')

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Load webpage", command=load_webpage)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The above code demonstrates the way you can achieve embedding html iframe in tkinter

Comment: Actually I was looking for the same solution, the method which you have suggested creating a new window is it possible to pack it in tkinter frame ?, I went through some documentation of pywebview beefily I couldn't find a solution to pack it in a tkinter frame. By any chance do you have a solution for this ?